# Spring Boot UnsatisfiedDependencyException Error creating bean with name unresolvable circular reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing an application with Spring Secuity where I have some custom filters, but I have problems configuring them correctly. Consider the following custom filters:

**LoginAuthenticationFilter:**

```
package com.espiritware.opusclick.restfullbackend.security.filters;


public class LoginAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
    
    private static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    private static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";
    private String credentialsCharset = "UTF-8";

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private TokenService tokenService;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Basic ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        
        String[] tokens = extractAndDecodeHeader(header, request);
        String email = tokens[0];
        String password = tokens[1];
        
        
        if(request.getServletPath().equals("/login/user")) {
            LoginAuthenticationFilter opusClickAuth= new OpusClickLoginAuthentication(email,password,true);
            try {
                Authentication result=authenticationManager.authenticate(opusClickAuth);
                if(result.isAuthenticated()) {
                    //SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
                    String jwtToken=tokenService.createAuthenticationToken(result,true);
                    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
                    response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + jwtToken);
                    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                }
            }catch(AuthenticationException failed) {
                //SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
        else {
            LoginAuthenticationFilter opusClickAuth= new OpusClickLoginAuthentication(email,password,false);
            try {
                Authentication result=authenticationManager.authenticate(opusClickAuth);
                if(result.isAuthenticated()) {
                    //SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
                    String jwtToken=tokenService.createAuthenticationToken(result,false);
                    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
                    response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + jwtToken);
                    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                }
            }catch(AuthenticationException failed) {
                //SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
    }
    
    protected String[] extractAndDecodeHeader(String header, HttpServletRequest request)
            throws IOException {

        byte[] base64Token = header.substring(6).getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] decoded;
        try {
            decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Token);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(
                    "Failed to decode basic authentication token");
        }

        String token = new String(decoded, getCredentialsCharset(request));

        int delim = token.indexOf(":");

        if (delim == -1) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid basic authentication token");
        }
        return new String[] { token.substring(0, delim), token.substring(delim + 1) };
    }
    
    protected String getCredentialsCharset(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        return this.credentialsCharset;
    }
    
    
    //No debe filtrar
    //false -> se activa
    //true -> no se activa
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        if(request.getServletPath().equals("/login/user")|| request.getServletPath().equals("/login/expert")){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

**JwtAuthenticationFilter:**

```
package com.espiritware.opusclick.restfullbackend.security.filters;

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private TokenService tokenService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        
        String jwtToken=extractToken(header);
        JwtAuthentication jwtAuthentication = new JwtAuthentication(jwtToken);
        
        try {
            Authentication result=authenticationManager.authenticate(jwtAuthentication);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }catch(AuthenticationException failed) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        authenticationManager.authenticate(jwtAuthentication);
    }
    
    protected String extractToken(String header){

        int delim = header.indexOf(" ");

        if (delim == -1) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid authentication token");
        }
        return header.substring(delim + 1);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        if(request.getServletPath().equals("/login/user")|| request.getServletPath().equals("/login/expert")){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**FilterConfigurations:**

```
package com.espiritware.opusclick.restfullbackend.security.filters.configurations;
@Configuration
public class FilterConfigurations {
    
    @Bean
    public LoginAuthenticationFilter opusClickLoginAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new OpusClickLoginAuthenticationFilter();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }
    
}
```

**WebAppSecurityConfiguration: (Fails)**

```
package com.espiritware.opusclick.restfullbackend.security;

@Configuration
public class WebAppSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
    @Autowired
    private LoginAuthenticationFilter opusClickLoginAuthenticationFilter;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    
     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         //http.oauth2Client();
         http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
         
         http.addFilterAt(LoginAuthenticationFilter,
                    BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
              .addFilterAt(jwtAuthenticationFilter, 
                    BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
         
         http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()  
                .httpBasic();
         
         
     }
     
     
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
//  @Bean
//  public LoginAuthenticationFilter LoginAuthenticationFilter() {
//      return new LoginAuthenticationFilter();
//  }
    
//  @Bean
//  public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
//      return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
//  }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

When I run the application it throws me the following exception:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.espiritware.opusclick.restfullbackend.OpusClickRestfullBackendApplication.main(OpusClickRestfullBackendApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'LoginAuthenticationFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webAppSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtAuthenticationFilter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManagerBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:175) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:170) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webAppSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtAuthenticationFilter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManagerBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManagerBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManagerBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 92 common frames omitted
```

However, when I comment on my entire `FilterConfigurations` class and I do the configuration of my filters beans directly in my `WebAppSecurityConfiguration` that works without problems:

**WebAppSecurityConfiguration: (Works Without Problems)**

```
package com.espiritware.opusclick.restfullbackend.security;

@Configuration
public class WebAppSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
    //@Autowired
    //private LoginAuthenticationFilter opusClickLoginAuthenticationFilter;
    
    //@Autowired
    //private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    
     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         //http.oauth2Client();
         http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
         
         http.addFilterAt(LoginAuthenticationFilter(),
                    BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
              .addFilterAt(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), 
                    BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
         
         http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()  
                .httpBasic();
         
         
     }
     
     
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LoginAuthenticationFilter LoginAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new LoginAuthenticationFilter();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

My Question is for what reason when I do **the same configuration** in my `FilterConfigurations` this stops working. I don't know if it is because this class found in another package. Someone who can explain the reason for this strange behavior?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I think that the `LoginAuthenticationFilter` and `JwtAuthenticationFilter` classes also need to be annotated with `@Configuration` annotation. Please check if this works.

Comment: both the filters are unecessary since spring security already has support for basic login (base64 enc header) and there is already a JWTFilter implemented in spring security 5 https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture i dont understand the point of using a framework if you plan on building stuff that is already in the framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely issue is related with two annotations: `@Autowired` for filters and `@Bean` annotation for `authenticationManagerBean` method. First of all need to understand that `WebAppSecurityConfiguration` class will be ready for use when both filters were autowired, but for successful autowiring both filters have relation on `AuthenticationManager`, and for that target we marked method `authenticationManagerBean` by `@Bean` annotation, and Spring tried to create `AuthenticationManager` in following way:

```
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return new AuthenticationManagerDelegator(this.authenticationBuilder, this.context);
}
```

as you can see for creating `AuthenticationManagerDelegator` we should have initialized two fields `authenticationBuilder` and `context`, but we have just started creating our `WebAppSecurityConfiguration` configuration bean, which will be marked as on creation until all fields are initialized, it was made specifically for avoiding of using uninitialized fields and getting `NullPointerException` exceptions.
But if review the second option of beans defitions, the workflow of beans creation was changed in following way:

1. `WebAppSecurityConfiguration` doesn't have fields for autowiring and we can easily create first of all configuration bean and unmark like `in creation`
2. after config bean was created, all `@Bean` annotations will be processed and on creating `authenticationManagerBean` we will not get the exception, because all fields were initialized when we was creating `WebAppSecurityConfiguration` configuration and now we can use all parent methods safely.

P.S. From my point of view, defining beans in following way:

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

is not good idea, because `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class will create all required components(beans) in correct order, and these methods from parent class were opened for customization implementation of bean in following way:

```
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return new CustomAuthenticationManager(...);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect explanation. Ideally we are not suppose to use Autowired in Configuration classes as Configuration classes are for bean definition and wiring so obviously when spring is performing bean wiring it can not inject Autowired objects which might have dependent objects which are not yet initialized and it gives InCreationException.

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate this issue you have to create a bean outside of the WebSecurity class since I noticed @autowired and @bean mess up sometimes by container, the reason is he can't identify the objects at the run time.

```
    @Component
public class PasswordEncoderConfiguration {

    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and you have to Autowired this to Websecurityconfig class by using below,

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
    // user for matching credentials
    // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
    auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

@Configuration is for Bean config, you can't use @Autowired to auto inject common beans, It seems that it only supports these two kind of inject
1)@Value("${bean.name}") String beanName;
2)@Inject Environment env; Environment is a special bean in spring

WebAppSecurityConfiguration is more like a @Component Bean, not a @Configuration Bean, you can use @Component and @Autowired together to inject filter Beans.

@Configuration is just for Bean config, if DemoService has a @Service annotion, you can inject it this way in @Configuration class

```
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter(DemoService demoService) {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter(demoService);
}
```

Comment: Yes. I can to use '@Autowired' to auto inject common beans in my annotated '@configuration' class and this one works fine. For example, if I want to configure an authentication provider using '@Autowired' in this same class. This works for me for instance: `@Configuration public class WebAppSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { @Autowired private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider; @Override protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider); }`